# When branch points lie in $\mathbb P^1\left(\overline{\mathbb Q}\right)$.

Tags: algebraic-curves, riemann-surfaces

I'm working on the following problem for several days without finding any solution:

---

Let $X$ be a complex smooth projective curve and suppose moreover that $X$ is defined over $\overline{\mathbb Q}$. Now consider a finite map $f:X\longrightarrow\mathbb P^1(\mathbb C)$ of degree $d$ and defined over $\overline{\mathbb Q}$.

**Question:**
I don't understand why the branch points of $f$ (if they exist) must lie in $\mathbb P^1\left(\overline{\mathbb Q}\right)\subseteq\mathbb P^1(\mathbb C)$. In particular I'd like to see why one requires that both the map $f$ and the curve $X$ must be defined over $\overline{\mathbb Q}$.

**Edit (Why the bounty):** I don't understand all the details of the given answer.

Comment: I assume this will be migrated to math.stackexchange, which seems more suitable.  Anyway, the reason to require the map to be defined over $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ is that otherwise you could have examples like $f:\mathbb{P}^1\to\mathbb{P}^1$ given by $z\mapsto z^2+\pi$, which has the non-algebraic branch point $\pi$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since everything is defined over $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$, $f$ is fixed by any automorphism of an extension of $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ which acts as the identity on $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$.  Since every such automorphism preserves the set of branch points of $f$, and this set is finite, it follows that the branch points must be in $\mathbb{P}^1(\overline{\mathbb{Q}})$.

Comment: What do you mean by "$f$ is fixed by any automorphism of an extension of $\overline{\mathbb Q}$"? $\textrm{Gal}(\mathbb C/\overline{\mathbb Q}$) acts in the natural way on $\mathbb P^1_\mathbb C$...

Comment: Let $K$ be an algebraically closed field which contains both $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ and the coordinates of the branch points of $f$, and let $\sigma$ be an automorphism of $K$ which acts as the identity on $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$.  Define $f^{\sigma}:X(K)\to\mathbb{P}^1(K)$ by $f^{\sigma}(P)=\sigma(f(\sigma^{-1}(P))$.  Let $S$ and $T$ be the sets of points in $\mathbb{P}^1(K)$ which have fewer than $d$ preimages in $X(K)$ under $f$ and $f^{\sigma}$, respectively.  Then $T=\sigma(S)$, and $S$ is the set of branch points of $f$ (so that $S$ is finite).  But since the equations defining $X$ ...

Comment: ... and $f$ have all their coefficients in
$\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$, in fact $f^{\sigma}(P)=f(P)$ for every $P\in X(K)$, so that $T=S$.  Thus $S$ is a finite subset of $\mathbb{P}^1(K)$ which is fixed by every automorphism of $K$ which acts as the identity on $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$.  It follows that $S$ is contained in $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$.  Is that clear?

Comment: Perfect. Thanks.